# Conditional probability manipulation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I currently have a problem like this:

Let $X_t:=B_t-t B_1$ be defined where $B_t$ is the standard Brownian motion with $t \in [0,1]$ and $0<t_1<...<t_n<1$. Then I want to show that

$(B_{t_1},...,B_{t_n}||B_{1}| < \frac{1}{n})$ converges in distribution to

$(X_{t_1},...,X_{t_n}).$

I actually have quite something.  I know that $(X_{t_1},...,X_{t_n},B_1)$ is Gaussian and that $(X_{t_i},B_1)$ are uncorrelated, i.e. independent.

So my idea is to rewrite $B_{t_i}= X_{t_i}+tB_1$, use somehow the independence to get rid of this conditional probability and then go for the limit.

Unfortunately, I don't get anywhere, as by reexpressing:

$(X_{t_1}+t_1B_1,...,X_{t_n}+t_nB_1||B_1| < \frac{1}{n})$ I still have the $B_1$'s flying around in $X_{t_1}+t_1B_1,...,X_{t_n}+t_nB_1.$

so one could try to use some kind of law of total probability

$$\mathbb{P}((B_{t_1} <a_1,...,B_{t_n} < a_n||B_{1}| < \frac{1}{n}))$$
$$=\int_{B_1^{-1}([\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n}])} \mathbb{P}(X_{t_1}+t_1 x < a_1,...,X_{t_n}+t_n x < a_n; B_1 =x).$$

But I don't see that this is helpful, as I now even have to deal with singular probabilities.

I really need a big hint how to proceed and how to exploit the independence in a correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Consider an expectation such as
$$
\Bbb E[f(X_{t_1}+B_1,\ldots,X_{t_n}+B_1)\,|\, |B_1|<1/n]
$$
where $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ is bounded and continuous. For convergence in distribution, you need to show that this expectation converges to
$$
\Bbb E[f(X_{t_1},\ldots,X_{t_n})]
$$
for each $f$ as specified. Using the independence of $(X_{t_1},\ldots,X_{t_n})$ and $B_1$, the numerator in the condition expectation can be written as
$$
\int_{(-1/n,1/n)}g(x)p_1(x)\,dx,
$$
where $g(x):=\Bbb E[f(X_{t_1}+x,\ldots,X_{t_n}+x)]$ and $p_1(x)$ is the standard normal density. Therefore you need to show that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} {\int_{(-1/n,1/n)}g(x)p_1(x)\,dx\over\int_{(-1/n,1/n)}p_1(y)\,dy}=g(0),
$$
which follows from a  bit of epsilonics because $g$ is bounded and continuous.